# String Cleaning

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have written following Code in Python to "clean" my strings:

```
 df['TextCleaning'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('[äöüßÖÄa-zA-Z].*[öäüßÖÄÜa-zA-Z0-9]', x)[0])
```

Now I makes "1.2.1 Hello" (Text) to just "Hello" (TextCleaning). 
What I want to do now is -> save the "1.2.1" in a own column. 
Can you help me?

Comment: You should provide us with some more sample data and your expected output.

Comment: Sample Data should be provided

Comment: word1 = " ".join(re.findall("[0-9.]+", output))
Like this?

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you

```
output =  "2.1.3 Hello world"
word1 = re.findall("\d+\.\d+\.\d", output )
```

Output

> ['2.1.3']

```
output =  "2.45.6 Hello 22.3.9 world"
word = re.findall("\d+\.\d+\.\d", output )
```

Output

> ['2.45.6', '22.3.9']

```
output =  "2.6 Hello 3.9 world"
word = re.findall("\d+\.\d", output )
```

Output

> ['2.6', '3.9']

Comment: I want as an output "2.1.3"

Answer (score 1):

You can do `expand=True`, with `pd.Series.str.split`:

```
df[['Text', 'TextCleaning'] = df['Text'].str.split('(?![öäüßÖÄÜa-zA-Z0-9])\s+(?=[äöüßÖÄa-zA-Z])', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Change the regex,

```
out =  "1.2.1 Hello "
new = " ".join(re.findall("[0-9.]+", out))
```

Output

> '1.2.1'